# Swiper.js with Rangeslider.js - Disabling Swiper.js touch event on Rangeslider.js onSlide callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, rangeslider

I am using Andre Ruffert's [rangeslider.js](https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js) on top of iDangerous' [swiper.js](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) but everytime I slide the rangeslider that I initialized, it also stimulates Swiper's touch slide event so both of them are sliding at the same time. Any approach I can use to disable the Swiper while I'm sliding Rangeslider? I am new to jQuery so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!--First Slide-->
    <div class="swiper-slide"> 
    <input type="range" class="rangeslider"/>
  </div>

  <!--Second Slide-->
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </div>

  <!--Etc..-->
```

JS

```
var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({

mode:'horizontal',
loop: true

});

$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({

polyfill: false,

// Callback function
onSlide: function(position, value) {},

// Callback function
onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {}
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the swiper-no-swiping class to the rangeslider:

```
$('input[type="range"]').addClass('swiper-no-swiping');
```